# relationship between custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

I created a custom post type called 'COURSE' and another custom post type called `PROFESSOR`. I want the course register to have a selection field (meta_boxes) with the teachers already registered. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: "Professor" should be a taxonomy, "Course" should be the post type. Multiple Professors can rule the Course, but not otherwise. Involve logics. Just a bit.

Comment: Can you give more details about the "teachers already registered" you mentioned? Are these associated with the professor custom post type? How do you know which ones are registered?

Comment: The simple answer to your question is: Yes. The question now is: What exactly did you try so far and where exactly are you stuck? Please update your question for clarification.